# Laravel eloquent ignore field in collection if empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, eloquent

So I have relationships with multiple tables:

```
    $business = Business::where('id', $id)
                    ->with('addresses')
                    ->with('location')
                    ->with('gallery')
                    ->get();
```

which brings back something like:

```
[{"id":100,"name":"Live","type":"4","email":"p.woj6@gmail.com","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":"Woas","image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":3,"api_key":null,"created_at":"2017-06-22 15:13:47","updated_at":"2017-06-22 15:13:47","addresses":[{"id":6,"firstline_address":"96","secondline_address":"Street","town":"","city":"","postcode":"","telephone":"","created_at":"2017-06-22 15:13:47","updated_at":"2017-06-22 15:13:47","pivot":{"business_id":100,"address_id":6}}],"location":{"id":95,"business_id":100,"longitude":-2.054067,"latitude":53.486755,"slug":"Live & Now","created_at":"2017-06-22 15:13:47","updated_at":"2017-06-22 15:13:47"},"gallery":null}]
```

However, I get an error that image which is null, doesn't exist in the collection. How can I say something like, if $business->image is empty, ignore it.

I tried:

```
    @if($business->image == "null")
        <img class="images" id="image" alt="no image" src="" />
    @else
        <img class="images" id="image" src="{{ asset($business->image) }}" />
    @endif
```

But with no success, I am looking for an efficient way because sometimes there is more than 1 field being empty. I would like to point out that data is outputted in a different places on the page i.e.

```
        @if($business->image == "null")
            <img class="images" id="image" alt="no image" src="" />
        @else
            <img class="images" id="image" src="{{ asset($business->image) }}" />
        @endif
<div id="right" class="map">
    <div id="map"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=AIzaSyAirYgs4Xnt9QabG9v56jsIcCNfNZazq50&language=en"></script>      
<!-- Displaying markers for business -->
                            @foreach ($business->location as $marker)
                                <script>
                            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                            zoom: 19,
                            center: {lat: {{$marker->latitude}}, lng: {{$marker->longitude}}}
                             });

                                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: {lat: {{$marker->latitude}}, lng: {{$marker->longitude}}},
                                map: map,
                                title: '{{$business->name}}'
  });

                        </script>
                        @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
Business::where('id', $id)
                ->with('addresses')
                ->with('location')
                ->with('gallery')
                ->get()
                ->reject(function($business){
                   return !$business->image;
                });
```

That will reject the businesses which have an empty image, if you are looking to still pull through the images you could do but populate the field you could try something like:

```
Business::where('id', $id)
                ->with('addresses')
                ->with('location')
                ->with('gallery')
                ->get()
                ->map(function($business){
                   return $business->image = !$business->image ? $business->image = 'N/A' : $business->image 
                });
```

Alternatively, you could check whether or not it is empty in your loop. There are lots of options here ^^

Also using: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators

You can do things like:

This will ensure there is always a postcode, whether it is an actual postcode or 0.

```
public function setPostcodeAttribute($value){
   $this->postcode = !$value ? 0 : $value;
}
```

Comment: yes but not only image is empty there are other bits that are empty as well so I don't want go reject ->image, reject ->address->postcode etc I want to reject everything that is null

Comment: In which case you would be better using eloquents getters and setters to ensure there is always a predictable piece of data to each of your fields, alternatively default it on the database.

Comment: never heard of getters and setters, could you provide an example based on my case?

Comment: weird thing is it says $business->addresses doesn't exist in current collection but it does actually, why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147439/discussion-between-przemek-wojtas-and-exohjosh).